# how to display special characters correctly in the website - html

Tags: html, special-characters

if you can check in my code here, you can see that the "umlauts" or the special letters in german are not displaying properly. How can i display them properly do i have to put something in my code? 
Thanks

oops jsfiddle is not working... so i posted it here:
thanks:
http://www.tintin.ws/files/newsletter006.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pages header says that it's in UTF-8, but the contents has:

```
0001e40: 6e64 204c f673 756e 6765 6e20 696e 2053  nd L.sungen in S
0002080: 7375 6e67 656e 2c20 6469 6520 6e69 6368  sungen, die nich
```

f6 for one of the non-ASCII characters - the content is encoded in Latin1 (ISO-8859-1).

Either make the page report that it is in Latin1, of re-encode the content into UTF-8.

Comment: @Douglas Leeder: shall I change this one? <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Your editor should have a setting somewhere which controls the output encoding it will use. Without knowing more details of your setup I can't really tell you.

Comment: I'd recommend putting the content into UTF-8 rather than changing the headers - it's more likely to work on more people's machines.

Comment: If it's a JSP you can declare it in the page directive... like this: `<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="your local jsp file encoding"%>` the content type sets the output encoding. pageEncoding is optional but says the compiler that your code is in X enconding. Try first only with contenttype.

Comment: @helios:thanks for this,i'm not really sure if i do understand this but what i did i already change the special characters as suggested above.

Comment: Oh, ok. I've simply pointed where to look for change the encoding of the result page. (You know, the JSP compiles to a servlet that send the text over the wire encoded in what you specified...)

Answer (score 1):

use this for character entity reference:

http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/reference/entity/

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this Character Reference:

http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html
```