# Can't display special characters HTML

Tags: html, css, special-characters

I have a problem recently I can't seem to be able to display special french characters like é.

This is my settings of my page :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

I tried `UTF-8` too and doesn't seem to work either.

I tried also using é and nothing.

Can someone help me ?

See [this website](http://karimreemka.free.fr)  (in the ABOUT section)

Comment: I think that's a side effect of "cufon", a service which replaces characters with images displaying a custom font. Maybe your font doesn't support french characters?!

Comment: ^ This. It's pretty obviously a Cufon problem. You should explicitly mention in your question that you're using it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131304/problems-displaying-french-accented-characters-in-utf-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually replace characters by its [HTML entities](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php) or using a [HTML escape tool](http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use html character entity for that.

[Reference](http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/reference/entity/)

Comment: See this link for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627188/how-to-display-special-characters-correctly-in-the-website-html

Answer (score 0):

This should be a valid french html document (According to web standards) . You did the right thing by choosing the iso-8859-1 character encoding, just at the wrong place.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">

    <head>
    <title>Example de document XHTML 1.0</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Portrait IntÃ©rieur</h1>
    <h2>Rainer-Maria Rilke</h2>
    <p>Ce ne sont pas des souvenirs<br />
    qui, en moi, t'entretiennent ;<br />
    tu n'es pas non plus mienne<br />
    par la force d'un beau dÃ©sir.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```